# NGINX reverse proxy to .netcore app gives bad gateway 502

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have an issue with Nginx configuration for reverse proxy. I try to get to the backend using the port http://localhost:5002/ but it gives bad gateway. The container with Nginx is HTTPS secured and the Angular app works and i can reach it from outside the server.

```
    # Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}


server {
  listen              443 ssl http2;
  listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name         XXX.app *.XXX.app;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/conf.d/XXX.app.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/XXX.app.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  sendfile            on;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;
    
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/angular4_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/angular4_access.log;
  
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
  
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;
}
```

Here is the error i get in the log when i want to login for example

```
2021/06/01 13:10:54 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.124.XXX.XX ,server: XXX.app, request: "POST /api/login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/login", host: "XXX.app", referrer: "https://XXX.app/auth/login"
```

Nginx is hosted in a container with the Angular app and the backend is in a different container.
What i want to achieve, is to have the connection to the backend using the reverse proxy and everything containing https://XXX.app/api to be redirected to the backend.

Tnx!

Later edit: Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  XXX-db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    container_name: XXX-db
    restart: always
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: x
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: x
        POSTGRES_DB: x
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - main

  app.api:
    image: xx/xx:api-dev
    container_name: XXX-web-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - logs:/app/Logs
      - templates:/app/wwwroot/templates
      - feedbacks:/app/wwwroot/feedbacks
    links:
      - XXX-db
    depends_on:
      - "XXX-db"
    ports:
      - 5002:5002
    networks:
      - main

  app.web:
    build:      
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    image: xx/xx:web-dev
    container_name: XXX-web
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - main

volumes:
  pgdata:
  logs:
  templates:
  feedbacks:
  certs:

networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't reach localhost:5002 is that the nginx container network is by default **Bridge**.

When running your nginx container, set the network to be **Host** as bellow:

```
docker run -d --network=host [your_nginx_docker_tag]
```

Although, in case of the two containers are services inside same docker-compose file as follow:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend-api:
    image: backend-api
    ports:
      - "5002:${INSIDE_API_PORT}"


  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "443:443"
```

You will be able to reach backend-api container with service name as follow (nginx.conf file)

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend-api:[put the INSIDE_API_PORT here];
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

}

Comment: How can i add the network mode to host? I have on every service the section
`networks:
  -main`

and at the end
`networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge`
By changing to host the driver, i get an error in compose up

Comment: I think you should keep bridge network and use the backend service name instead of localhost inside your nginx file configuration

Comment: I did the change as you mentioned, use the service name and then the container name but got the same error Bad Gateway...

Comment: I made some changes to my answer
you need to use the port inside the backend container, maybe not 5002 in your case

Comment: You were correct! I changed the port for app.api to 5002:80 and in nginx added http://app.api:80 for the proxy pass and worked.
Tnx